# Manage shared data in multi-thread-process applications

Tags: python, web, locking, mutex, shared-memory

I have a web application in Python. Each API request is handled in a new thread. Therefore, I need to use mutexes to prevent race conditions.

However, some threads can spawn new processes. One thread might spawn a new process while another thread holds a locked mutex.

As a result, the spawned process will have the mutex in a locked state due to the implementation details of the fork system call in Linux.

If this process attempts to acquire such a mutex, it will enter a deadlock state, even though no one is actually holding the mutex in this process.

How to avoid deadlock?

One idea is to track the process ID (PID) of the process and update the lock when it changes. However, this approach is also prone to errors. In cases where the spawned process creates multiple threads, they can still enter a race condition:

```py
import multiprocessing
import os
import time
from threading import Lock, Thread

lock = Lock()
pid = os.getpid()
shared_data = 0


def spawn_2_threads_and_wait(target1, target2):
    ts = [Thread(target=target1), Thread(target=target2)]

    for t in ts:
        t.start()

    for t in ts:
        t.join()


def process_thread_task1():
    global lock, pid
    print("Lock state:", lock.locked())
    if os.getpid() != pid:
        time.sleep(1)  # wait for a second thread will come here to show race condition
        pid = os.getpid()
        lock = Lock()

    with lock:
        print("Got a lock 1")
        time.sleep(100)


def process_thread_task2():
    global lock, pid
    print("Lock state:", lock.locked())
    if os.getpid() != pid:
        time.sleep(1)  # wait for a first thread will come here to show race condition
        pid = os.getpid()
        time.sleep(1)  # wait for a first thread will acquire the lock
        lock = Lock()  # overwrite lock

    with lock:  # Get wrong lock
        print("Got a lock 2")  # Error! Will no wait 100 seconds sleep of first thread!!
        time.sleep(100)


def process_task():
    spawn_2_threads_and_wait(target1=process_thread_task1, target2=process_thread_task2)


def thread_task1():
    with lock:
        global shared_data
        shared_data += 1
        time.sleep(1)  # thread_task2 will spawn a process with locked mutex here


def thread_task2():
    time.sleep(0.1)  # wait for thread_task1 will lock the mutex
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_task)
    p.start()
    p.join()


def main():
    spawn_2_threads_and_wait(target1=thread_task1, target2=thread_task2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Currently, I have a few options:

1. Be very vigilant in monitoring all processes and threads and avoid code like the one mentioned above.
2. Use a mutex manager (e.g., Redis locks or multiprocessing.Manager()).

Which approach is more appropriate? What is the common practice in such cases? How to manage shared data in multi-thread-process applications?

Thank you.

Comment: You could change the start method of multiprocessing from "fork" to "spawn" but this may cause other problems.

Comment: @michael-butscher Do you mean performance problems?
If don't take that into account, this solution seems suitable for me.
What worries me more - is such an issue typical for multi-threaded applications, or am I trying to do something conceptually wrong? (I'm a beginner in multithreading)

Comment: Performance, memory (if there is a lot of read-only data which should be shared between the processes) and you must be careful what to place outside and what inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"`guard. A combination of multithreading and multiprocessing should only be used if you have things to wait for (mainly IO operations) for the threads **and** CPU bound operations for the processes to do.